# how to calculate mean value of each column within range of quantile?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate mean value of each column but only consider values are within range of quantile, like 20%-80% only.

Here is why I have done, but not complete

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,20,2,2,3,50,7,8,15,20,35,50,70],"B":[10,100,20,20,200,30,50,70,80,150,200,350,500,700]})
df
    A   B
0   1   10
1   1   100
2   20  20
3   2   20
4   2   200
5   3   30
6   50  50
7   7   70
8   8   80
9   15  150
10  20  200
11  35  350
12  50  500
13  70  70

then find q20 and 180 for each column using np.quantile()

q20=np.quantile(df,0.2,axis=0)
q20

array([ 2., 26.])

q80=np.quantile(df,0.8,axis=0)
q80

array([ 41., 260.])
```

Now How do I filter the values between q20 and q80 for each column

I am doing below then I got an error

```
mask=(a>q20)&(a<q80)

TypeError: Cannot compare a Categorical for op __gt__ with type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.
If you want to compare values, use 'np.asarray(cat) <op> other'.
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rank` with `pct`

```
out = df[df.rank(pct=True).ge(0.2) & df.rank(pct=True).le(0.8)].mean()
```

out:

```
A     12.444444
B    110.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: wow Panda Kim, you saved my night. Thank you so much, I appreciate it